# Do I have to use flag in c++?

Tags: c++

Here is the problem I'm facing. The user is to enter a number and if the number is in the array, I want to print this as a valid number, otherwise I want to print this as not valid number.

However this code isn't working; it is only printing `Not Valid`

I looked at other code that was similar. They used a `bool` flag.

Why do I need to use a flag in this program and when do I need to use a flag?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE=6;

    int arry[SIZE]={5658845,4520125,1230493,4856970,2078594,2393741};

    int number;
    cout <<"Enter the number"<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        cin>>number;

        if(arry[i]==number)
           cout<<"This is valid number"<<endl;
         else
           cout << "This is not valid number"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What question? What flag? We're lacking context to answer (or even identify) a question.

Comment: Do you want to enter 6 numbers or 1 number and check it against all 6?

Comment: sorry. If I enter the number which is in the array, print "This is valid number". If I enter the other number which is not in the array, print "this is not valid number".

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use a variable as a flag - that is an implementation choice.    You need to get the logic right, either way.    Do you intend to input one value and check if it is in the array, or enter six values and check if they are in the array?

Answer (score 3):

The way your code is implemented, you are reading the user's input WHILE searching the array.  You have implemented a guessing game:  "Is the 1st number exactly X?"  "Is the 2nd number exactly X?" And so on for each number in the array.

Is that what you want? If not, if you want the user to enter only 1 number and then you check if the number exists anywhere in the array, you need to read the user's input BEFORE entering the search loop (this is when the `bool` comes into play), eg:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 6;
    const int arry[SIZE] = {5658845, 4520125, 1230493, 4856970, 2078594, 2393741};

    int number;
    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (arry[i] == number)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
        cout << "This is valid number" << endl;
    else
        cout << "This is not valid number" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use the `std::find()` algorithm instead of searching manually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 6;
    const int arry[SIZE] = {5658845, 4520125, 1230493, 4856970, 2078594, 2393741};

    int number;
    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    const int *end = arry + SIZE;
    if (find(arry, end, number) != end)
        cout << "This is valid number" << endl;
    else
        cout << "This is not valid number" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**My code not working**

If you wanna check value is in array, you check all element in array.
But you do not.

**Do i have to use flag in c++?**

Flag is for a status. So in many code, define the flags and use this for option.

like this

```
const int SINGLE_THREAD = 0;
const int MULTI_THREAD = 1;
/...

bool select_server_type(int option)
{
    //....
}

select_server_type(SINGLE_THREAD);
```

But, you not must use flag in all situation.

In yor situation, you can make fucntion to check them like this.

(I know this is very unsafe code. But in your level, this code will be understandable code)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//check all element in array
bool match(int* arr, int size, int value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if(arr[i] == value)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE=6;

    int arry[SIZE]={5658845,4520125,1230493,4856970,2078594,2393741};

    int number;
    cout <<"Enter the number"<<endl;

    cin>>number;

    if(match(arry, SIZE, number))
        cout<<"This is valid number"<<endl;
    else
        cout << "This is not valid number"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173599/discussion-between-rajat-jain-and-standard-kim).

Answer (score 1):

You can use flag whenever you want to see is an instance or condition occur. You can write your program as follows. Actually, flag is just a variable in which you can save a condition to check further.

```
const int SIZE=6;

int arry[SIZE]={5658845,4520125,1230493,4856970,2078594,2393741};

int number;
cout <<"Enter the number"<<endl;
cin >> number;
int flag = 0;
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++{
    if(arry[i]==number){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==1)
    cout<<"This is valid number"<<endl;
else
    cout << "This is not valid number"<<endl;
```

As here we have to check whether the condition if the loop ever becomes true. So, we use flag so that we can get the result outside of the loop.

In this case you can also do:

```
int flag=0;
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++{
    if(arry[i]==number){
        cout<<"This is valid number"<<endl;"
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag!=1)
    cout << "This is not valid number"<<endl;
```